# Why don't the applications run by Powershell appear on remote desktop but appear in task manager?

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, start-process

I'm using Windows Powershell to access virtual machines. When I try to run a program using Powershell by "Start-Process notepad.exe" or ".\notepad.exe", The notepad seems to appear in task manager but doesn't appear on the desktop. I use "Start-Process notepad.exe -WindowsStyle maximized" command but nothing has changed. For other applications the issue is the same. They appear in task manager as running but are not available on desktop.

How can I fix it? How can I make the applications run by Powershell available on remote desktop?

Comment: You cannot remotely access the existing interactive local session with Powershell remoting.

Comment: There is no problem about accessing the remote desktop.For example,  I can read the txt file by "get-content" command. The issue is running programs on remote computer and the programs' invisibilty on desktop.

Comment: There's a distinct difference between reading a file and interacting with an existing interactive local session. Did you read the marked answer from the  thread BACON shared a link of?